# Explicit locks acquisition order, between signaled threads and threads initially acquiring the lock, in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

The Javadoc for the method [`Condition.newCondition()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#newCondition%28%29) states "*The ordering of lock reacquisition for threads returning from waiting methods is the same as for threads initially acquiring the lock, which is in the default case not specified, but for fair locks favors those threads that have been waiting the longest.*"

Does that mean that, with explicit locks, threads awakening from a condition compete for the lock acquisition together with the threads initially acquiring it, just as it occurs with implicit locks?

In other words, having two groups of threads, one who is trying to acquire the lock for the first time, and one who are trying to re-acquire the lock after having waited on a condition and being signaled, is the latter favored over the former on the lock acquisition?

Does the lock fairness value affects in any way the lock acquisition order of the these two groups?

Comment: It should be "undefined" (i.e. it actually depends on your OS thread scheduler) unless you have a fair lock. The OS probably does not know whether a thread was already waiting and is now re-acquiring or not so there should be no distinction between those groups. Fair locks on the other hand prefer the longest waiting regardless of the reason why they are waiting.

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, having two groups of threads, one who is trying to acquire the lock for the first time, and one who are trying to re-acquire the lock after having waited on a condition and being signaled, is the latter favored over the former on the lock acquisition?

No, unless the `Lock` is “fair”, it’s most likely the opposite: typical implementations favor the thread just acquiring the `Lock` because it has less overhead to let that thread succeed instead of putting that thread to sleep and wake up another.

> Does the lock fairness value affects in any way the lock acquisition order of the these two groups?

No, the lock acquisition makes no difference at that point. When a thread waiting on a `Condition` is signaled there might be other threads waiting longer for a first time acquisition. And a “fair” `Lock` will prefer the longest waiting thread.

Answer (score 0):

For fair locks, a therad which reqcquires the lock after having singaled has to line up at the end of the lock queue.

The following short program demonstrates this behavior.

- T1 acquires the lock first and then invokes await on a condition associated with this lock.
- T2 then acquires the lock and waits until T3 tried to acquire the lock as well and then invokes a signal on the condition.
- T3 waits some time before acuiring the lock which is hold by T2.

When T2 invokes signal, then T1 tries to reacquire the lock. When T2 releases the lock, then both T1 and T3 are competing for the lock, but T3 gets the lock first.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Lock r = new ReentrantLock(true);
        final Condition c = r.newCondition();

        Thread t1 = new Thread( () -> { 
            System.out.println("T1 try lock");
            r.lock(); 
            System.out.println("T1 got lock");
            System.out.println("T1 invokes await and releases lock");
            try { c.await(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            System.out.println("T1 reqcquired lock");
            r.unlock();
        } );
        Thread t2 = new Thread( () -> {
            sleep(50);
            System.out.println("T2 try lock");
            r.lock();
            System.out.println("T2 got lock");
            sleep(100);
            c.signal();
            System.out.println("T2 signaled");
            sleep(100);
            r.unlock();
        } );
        Thread t3 = new Thread( () -> {
            sleep(100);
            System.out.println("T3 try lock");
            r.lock();
            System.out.println("T3 got lock");
            r.unlock();
        } );
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

    static void sleep(long millis) {
        try { Thread.sleep(millis); } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
    }

}
```

The output is

```
T1 try lock
T1 got lock
T1 invokes await and releases lock
T2 try lock
T2 got lock
T3 try lock
T2 signaled
T3 got lock
T1 got signal and reqcquired lock
```